# C++ packing different data types into one long variable

Tags: c++, binary, packing

I've got into a trap trying to pack a couple of variables into a one variable 8 byte long.

Basically, I've got a couple of short items which have small binary size and I need to pack them together to send into class which must be able to depack it back.

So I made the following:

```
typedef unsigned long long PACKAGE; // 8 byte (shows as _int64 in debug)
(sizeof returns '8')
unsigned int dat1   = 25;  // 1 byte long max
unsigned int dat2   = 1;   // 4 bit long max
unsigned int dat3   = 100; // 2 byte long max
unsigned int dat4   = 200; // 4 byte long max
unsigned int dat5   = 2;   // 4 bit long max
```

Then I make a variable of PACKAGE type which is empty (0)

```
PACKAGE pack = 0;
```

And I want to throw variables into that pack using binary operations, I do:

```
pack = (dat1 << 56) | (dat2 << 52) | (dat3 << 36) | (dat4 << 4) | dat5;
```

it works only half-good, I calculated that I must get decimal value of pack equals to `2526526262902525058`, or

```
0010001100010000000001100100000000000000000000000000110010000010
```

as binary, however istead I'm getting `588254914`, or
‭`00100011000100000000111011000010‬` as binary
which is somehow correct at it's tail and head but the middle part is missing off somewhere.

And when this is done I'm still about to extract the data back somehow.

Comment: What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: You could use a union with a `uint64_t` and a bit-field structure perhaps? Though type-punning like that breaks the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: An int variable shifted by 56 positions is implicitly shifting it only by 24 positions which explains why u r getting the wrong answer. That is assuming an int is 4 bytes...

Comment: @Robᵩ, well, my question is 'what I'm doing wrong?' and 'how to make it right?'. Honestly I'm not experienced with binary operations much as I used standart types all the way before so might just be missing something obvious. But web is not really helping on topic so far.

Comment: @jinxed Use a bitfield structure insteadt.

Comment: @Madhusudhan, ah, that might be the problem, perhaps. I usually need info only from the first byte out of 4 int bytes. Except for dat4 and 3 - from which I need 4 and 2 bytes respectively. Maybe I need some half-way variable of 1 byte size as a middle man?

Comment: `int` is a strange beast. Depending on the compiler it could be anywhere from 16 bits long to, for now at least, 64 bits. This makes overflowing it by accident relatively easy. If your compiler has support for them, consider using [fixed width integers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: `dat1 << 56` but `dat1` was declared as `unsigned int`. *If* `unsigned int` is 32bits on your platform then that is undefined behaviour - *if* it is 64bits then you are good.

Comment: God bless this site and all of you :)

Comment: @jinxed feel free to praise, but *please* don't bring imaginary beings like "god" into it. Yes, I do in fact find that offensive.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm as well so feel free to take as a generalized, popularity-accepted frase standing for 'thank you, best wishes'

Comment: You could then have just written that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use a [bitfield](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) struct to represent such type (also use `uint64_t` to be sure of the available size):

```
union PACKAGE {
    struct bits {
        uint64_t dat1 : 8;  // 1 byte long max
        uint64_t dat2 : 4;  // 4 bit long max
        uint64_t dat3 : 16; // 2 byte long max
        uint64_t dat4 : 32; // 4 byte long max
        uint64_t dat5 : 4;  // 4 bit long max
    };
    uint64_t whole; // for convenience
};
```

---

As mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749590/c-packing-different-data-types-into-one-long-variable/38750033?noredirect=1#comment64874396_38750033) you could even use the [`uint_least64_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) data type, to ensure your target supports it (since availability of `uint64_t` is optional from the current c++ standard):

```
union PACKAGE {
    struct bits {
        uint_least64_t dat1 : 8;  // 1 byte long max
        uint_least64_t dat2 : 4;  // 4 bit long max
        uint_least64_t dat3 : 16; // 2 byte long max
        uint_least64_t dat4 : 32; // 4 byte long max
        uint_least64_t dat5 : 4;  // 4 bit long max
    };
    uint_least64_t whole; // for convenience
};
```

Comment: Future readers: Take note of the use of `uint64_t`. This type, if supported by your compiler, will guarantee an unsigned 64 bit integer. The definition can be found in `<cstdint>`

Comment: @user4581301 It's actually supported by the standard.

Comment: Thanks, I might just go for it actually - just got to spend some time reading stuff on the matter, haven't crossed my ways with bitfields before.

Comment: @jinxed De nada. You might consider to change your accept, since this should be the _canonical way_ to handle such structures.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's actually optional by the standard.

Comment: @rubenvb Samples of any _modern_ compiler implementations, which don't provide `uint64_t`?

Comment: Compiler will be quite loud if `uint64_t` is not present, so you'll know early if you don't beforehand. Most likely it will only be missing in compilers for light-weight embedded systems.

Comment: On the other hand, `uint_least64_t` is not optional, if you can afford to risk a bit of waste. Why this is mandatory and `uint64_t` isn't probably has a really interesting story behind it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's irrelevant. If you say it's supported by (with which you probably mean included and fully defined by) the Standard, you're wrong. These kinds of assumptions make code not-so-portable in 10-20 years. Smells just like the "long is 64-bit" debacle in the cross-platform world.

Comment: @rubenvb _"If you say it's supported by (with which you probably mean included and fully defined by) the Standard, you're wrong."_ Where did I do so in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `sizeof(unsigned int) != sizeof(unsigned long long)`, the left operand of each shift is the wrong type. Each shift operation is being truncated (probably to 32 bits).

Try, for example:

```
typedef unsigned long long PACKAGE; // 8 byte (shows as _int64 in debug)
(sizeof returns '8')
unsigned long long dat1   = 25;  // 1 byte long max
unsigned long long dat2   = 1;   // 4 bit long max
unsigned long long dat3   = 100; // 2 byte long max
unsigned long long dat4   = 200; // 4 byte long max
unsigned long long dat5   = 2;   // 4 bit long max

pack = (dat1 << 56) | (dat2 << 52) | (dat3 << 36) | (dat4 << 4) | dat5;
```

or:

```
typedef unsigned long long PACKAGE; // 8 byte (shows as _int64 in debug)
(sizeof returns '8')
unsigned int dat1   = 25;  // 1 byte long max
unsigned int dat2   = 1;   // 4 bit long max
unsigned int dat3   = 100; // 2 byte long max
unsigned int dat4   = 200; // 4 byte long max
unsigned int dat5   = 2;   // 4 bit long max

pack = ((PACKAGE)dat1 << 56) | ((PACKAGE)dat2 << 52) | ((PACKAGE)dat3 << 36) | ((PACKAGE)dat4 << 4) | (PACKAGE)dat5;
```

Note: Okay, in actuality each shift operation in which the right-hand operand is greater than the size of the left-hand type, in bits invokes *undefined behavior*. The typical undefined behavior is truncation, but any other behavior, up to and including global thermonuclear war, is allowed by the standard.

Comment: I'll let somebody else answer on how to use bitfields.

Comment: Yes, sizeof(unsigned int) != sizeof(unsigned long long) - give me a moment to try this out, thanks

Comment: Both ways working, so might be the problem of compiling it in 32bit mode resulting in undefined behavior? Eh, that's convinient. I may better try to look the other way, maybe fixed width ints or bitfields as folks've suggested above...